# Giving 100% width to a:hover, text position

Tags: css, hover, width, position

This might be silly or very easy to do, but I have no clue how to change text position, not affecting hover effect (it's width is exact size as it's parent div/transparent block). For better understanding here's example image.

1. On hover, **red** par is set in action.
2. **Blue** block is content going on top, so that red bar disapears under it, but having 100%, it's now shows on both side of
   transparent block.
3. Finally, **yellow** block is place where the
       navigation needs to be placed (again, hover state doesn't changes)

[image: http://i40.tinypic.com/imms6f.jpg // having under 10res points, sorry about direct link]

Really, I'm out of ideas, or to be more precise, without any idea on how to do it. Is it even possible with css?

Comment: sorry, but it's really not clear what you're trying to achieve. is the image a screenshot of the design, or just a quick sketch? blue block is partly over the menu? yellow = second navigation block? ...

Comment: Here's a demo that sort of looks like the image: http://jsfiddle.net/AvNnL/ I can't figure out what the goal or problem is...

Comment: thanks for adding live example! yes, ptriek, it's screen shot from browser. yellow block is only showing where text should be located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I recommend using **padding-left** css property. It does not change you hover and if you set the padding as a sum of width of the blue rectangle + width of its right overflowing part, you get your text where you want to.

Set padding-left to he red rectangle.

Comment: if I set it to red rectangle (in my case #nav li a), then text moves to right and red bar increases +px to right side braking out of container. while setting it straight to :hover, text jumps away from it's old position to new(not needed, by default it must be on right side). isn't so easy...

Comment: So you need to subtract the value you added to padding from the elements width - in standard browsers. Keep the sum same. Here is something about box model - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: unfortunately, I can't comment my first entry, so I do it here.
thanks for adding live example! yes, ptriek, it's screenshot from browser. yellow block is only showing where navigation should be located.also, it was navs old position, hover effect forced me to move it. imagine navigation on right side, video is on left. if user hovers over items, red block appears with 100% width and is visible in full lenght of parent div. hope u got what I mean...

Comment: Try this one - add span to the HTML <nav><ul><li><a><span>text</span></a></li></nav> and then use relative positioning to span.

Comment: can u please give example about subtracting on above example (made by  Madmartigan)?